# Free & easy blog platform with option to let others see it only with a password, no need to register

Tags: blog

I liked the ideas of tumblr, especially that one can upload videos (although altogether the site didn't work very smoothly for me) but there others only get access with password **and** registration.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "others only get access with password and registration". Is it to view posts? Because if that is the case, then tumblr lets you view other people's posts without registering. Or is it to post stories without being the owner of the blog?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for asking. As far as I saw tumblr only lets others see password protected blogs if they also register. Wix allows to share the password so they can see it without registration but there as far as I saw you cannot upload videos (only via youtube or vimeo where I think they don't have password a protection option). In my blog others should be able to comment, not necessarily add their own posts (although if that is optional it would be a plus. Another big plus would be an option to allow more different language versions).

Answer (score 1):

You might try Wordpress ([How to Password Protect Your WordPress without User Registration](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-password-protect-your-wordpress-without-user-registration/)).

**A word of caution** : As there's a need to install an additional plugin, you will probably need to install it on an owned server/domain (wordpress plate-form will make you pay if you want to install plugins)...but it's free to [download](https://wordpress.org/download/) and use.

Comment: I already tried installing WordPress, stopped after failing step one of the explanation, and a whole system plus an additional plugin is not really easy to use.

Comment: You're right, you asked for easy :) However, some hosting companies use things on their servers like softaculous. It allows you to install very easily Wordpress, for example.

Comment: He needs to set a proper database to install Wordpress. I don't think the others are easier.